# Upload image using ajax and PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Here is my problem. I tried to upload image and I store images in corresponding folder and image path in database with the help of this URL.

http://www.lionblogger.com/how-to-upload-file-to-server-using-php-save-the-path-in-mysql/.

When i tried that way i will get correct answer. After i tried same code with AJAX is not working properly. I dont know what mistake I did. Below is my code.

HTML code

```
<div class="input-group form-group">
<label> Upload Your Photo </label>                            
<input type="file" name="upload_photo" id="upload_photo">
</div>
<div class="">
<input type="submit"  class="btn btn-success btn-lg " name="upload_files" id="upload_files" value="UPLOAD" >
</div>
```

AJAX code

```
$("#upload_files").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var upload_photo1 = $('#upload_photo').val();
        var photo= upload_photo1.split('\\').pop().split('/').pop();
        var datas="photo="+photo;
    alert(datas);
     if(photo==''){
      sweetAlert({
        title: "WARNING!!!",
        text: "Please Upload All Corresponding Documents And Try Again !!!!",
        type: "warning"
      });
     } else {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'php/upload_files.php',
        data:datas
        }).done(function( data ) {
            alert(data);
         });
    }
});
```

And my PHP file
Upload_files.php

```
<?php
    $fileExistsFlag = 0; 
    $fileName = $_POST['photo'];
    var_dump($fileName);
    $link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","spark") or die("Error ".mysqli_error($link));

    $query = "SELECT filename FROM filedetails WHERE filename='$fileName'"; 
    $result = $link->query($query) or die("Error : ".mysqli_error($link));
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        if($row['filename'] == $fileName) {
            $fileExistsFlag = 1;
        }       
    }

    if($fileExistsFlag == 0)
    { 
        $target = "files/";     
        $fileTarget = $target.$fileName;    
        $tempFileName = $_FILES["fileName"]["tmp_name"];
        $fileDescription = $_POST['Description'];   
        $result = move_uploaded_file($tempFileName,$fileTarget);
        $ext = end(explode('.', $fileName));
        if ($_FILES["fileName"]["size"] > 2097152)
         {
         echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
         $uploadOk = 0;
         }
      else if($ext != "jpg" && $ext != "png" && $ext != "jpeg"&& $ext != "gif" ) 
      {
         echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
         $uploadOk = 0;
      }
    else
    {
        if($result) { 
            echo "Your file <html><b><i>".$fileName."</i></b></html> has been successfully uploaded";       
            $query = "INSERT INTO filedetails(filepath,filename,description) VALUES ('$fileTarget','$fileName','$fileDescription')";
            $link->query($query) or die("Error : ".mysqli_error($link));            
        }
        else {          
            echo "Sorry !!! There was an error in uploading your file";         
        }
    }   
        mysqli_close($link);
    }

    else {
        echo "File <html><b><i>".$fileName."</i></b></html> already exists in your folder. Please rename the file and try again.";
        mysqli_close($link);
    }   
?>
```

Error what im getting is [image]

Please Bear my doubts.. Beginner of PHP.Kindly Help me out of this problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery ajax File Upload php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23980733/jquery-ajax-file-upload-php)

Comment: You only send the name of the file (if any) in your ajax request, not the contents of the file. See linked topic for a sample code for file uploading.

Answer (score 1):

You have serious issues with your code in both js and php. You have not uploaded the file at all. You have just uploaded the file name. There is no description as input but in your php code you have a description variable unhandled. You have handled the file with the wrong name. 
Try uploading the file with FormData. First, use the form tag with an id

```
<form id='myform'>
<div class="input-group form-group">
<label> Upload Your Photo </label>                            
<input type="file" name="upload_photo" id="upload_photo">
</div>
<div class="">
<input type="submit"  class="btn btn-success btn-lg " name="upload_files" id="upload_files" value="UPLOAD" >
</div>
</form>
```

and in the js,

```
    formData = new FormData($("#myForm")[0]);
    formData.append("photo", photo);//your photo name
```

and in the AJAX request, write

```
 data: formData,
```

and in your php file

```
<?php
 $fileExistsFlag = 0; 
 $fileDescription ='No idea where this came from';
 $fileName = $_POST['photo'];
 $link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","spark") or die("Error ".mysqli_error($link));

 $query = "SELECT filename FROM filedetails WHERE filename='$fileName'"; 
 $result = $link->query($query) or die("Error : ".mysqli_error($link));
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
     if($row['filename'] == $fileName) {
         $fileExistsFlag = 1;
     }       
 }

 if($fileExistsFlag == 0)
 { 
     $target = "files/";     
     $fileTarget = $target.$fileName;    
     $tempFileName = $_FILES["upload_photo"]["tmp_name"];
     $result = move_uploaded_file($tempFileName,$fileTarget);
     $ext = end(explode('.', $fileName));
     if ($_FILES["upload_photo"]["size"] > 2097152)
      {
      echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
      $uploadOk = 0;
      }
   else if($ext != "jpg" && $ext != "png" && $ext != "jpeg"&& $ext != "gif" ) 
   {
      echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
      $uploadOk = 0;
   }
 else
{
    if($result) { 
        echo "Your file <html><b><i>".$fileName."</i></b></html> has been successfully uploaded";       
        $query = "INSERT INTO filedetails(filepath,filename,description) VALUES ('$fileTarget','$fileName','$fileDescription')";
        $link->query($query) or die("Error : ".mysqli_error($link));            
    }
    else {          
        echo "Sorry !!! There was an error in uploading your file";         
    }
}   
    mysqli_close($link);
}

else {
    echo "File <html><b><i>".$fileName."</i></b></html> already exists in your folder. Please rename the file and try again.";
    mysqli_close($link);
}   
?>
```

Comment: in js file what that photo means.. I got error in that line

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: photo is not defined this is the error

Comment: @KavyaShree  `var photo= upload_photo1.split('\\').pop().split('/').pop();` Its from your own code. The code is incomplete. You have to write the complete code yourself

Comment: but i dont know how to use formdata

Comment: @KavyaShree See http://www.javascripture.com/FormData and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21044798/how-to-use-formdata-for-ajax-file-upload

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not passing the file data - just the name.
In the example from your link there is a form that is beeing submitted (with enctype="multipart/form-data" which means you are passing binary data).

The php code accesses the file data through the variable $_FILES["Filename"]["tmp_name"]; because when uploading a file it is stored in a temp folder with a temporary internal name (that's the tmp_name element).
By simply changing 'Filename' to 'fileName' in the index does not give you your actual file data.

So a quick solution is to wrap the input field in an acutal form (with the enctype="multipart/form-data"), catch the submit event and pass the whole form data in the ajax call - so instead of

```
data:datas
```

you pass

```
data: new FormData(this)
```

check out the example here:
http://www.formget.com/ajax-image-upload-php/

EDIT: @khandelwaldeval beat me to the answer ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks complicated try using this

```
            <form id="picupload">
            <input type="file" accept="image/png, image/jpeg, image/gif" id="upload_photo" name="upload_photo" Required/>
            <button type="submit" name="save" class="btn btn-theme step6"></button>
            </form>
```

javascript for submission

```
        <script>
         $("#picupload").submit(function(e) {

                $.ajax({
                  url: "php/upload_files.php", 
                      type: "POST",             
                      data: new FormData(this), 
                      contentType: false,       
                      cache: false,            
                      processData:false,      
                                success: function(data)
                                {
                                 alert(data);
                                 }

                              });
         e.preventDefault(); 
         });

        </script>
```

use your php code for processing the file

```
        <?php
         $fileExistsFlag = 0; 
         $fileDescription ='No idea where this came from';
         $fileName = $_POST['upload_photo'];
         $link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","spark") or die("Error ".mysqli_error($link));

         $query = "SELECT filename FROM filedetails WHERE filename='$fileName'"; 
         $result = $link->query($query) or die("Error : ".mysqli_error($link));
         while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
             if($row['filename'] == $fileName) {
                 $fileExistsFlag = 1;
             }       
         }

         if($fileExistsFlag == 0)
         { 
             $target = "files/";     
             $fileTarget = $target.$fileName;    
             $tempFileName = $_FILES["upload_photo"]["tmp_name"];
             $result = move_uploaded_file($tempFileName,$fileTarget);
             $ext = end(explode('.', $fileName));
             if ($_FILES["upload_photo"]["size"] > 2097152)
              {
              echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
              $uploadOk = 0;
              }
           else if($ext != "jpg" && $ext != "png" && $ext != "jpeg"&& $ext != "gif" ) 
           {
              echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
              $uploadOk = 0;
           }
         else
        {
            if($result) { 
                echo "Your file <html><b><i>".$fileName."</i></b></html> has been successfully uploaded";       
                $query = "INSERT INTO filedetails(filepath,filename,description) VALUES ('$fileTarget','$fileName','$fileDescription')";
                $link->query($query) or die("Error : ".mysqli_error($link));            
            }
            else {          
                echo "Sorry !!! There was an error in uploading your file";         
            }
        }   
            mysqli_close($link);
        }

        else {
            echo "File <html><b><i>".$fileName."</i></b></html> already exists in your folder. Please rename the file and try again.";
            mysqli_close($link);
        }   
        ?>
```